# Sometimes suddenly a subdomain cannot be found

Tags: webserver, dns

I have a website hosted by an external webhosting company.

Sometimes, when I am uploading a file, suddenly my webbrowser says the page cannot be found. But a minute ago, it could!

What are possible reasons for that? Does it have something to do with DNS?

By the way, it's about a subdomain: http://subdomain.example.com.

(PS: If this question is is offtopic, on what StackExchange website should I post it instead?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a subdomain is domain on its own so `sub.example.com` is passed to the DNS first, if no specific record is found for this subdomain, the request is passed to the IP of the top domain (`example.com`). On that server the request is made again and the server will act accordingly.

Therefore, I assume your current ISP does not resolve the subdomain, and the top domain is passed the same request, and as servers on their own tend to be a little less reliable than DNS servers from, say, your ISP or Google's DNS, or OpenDNS, I assume it's just a small glitch because of slightly worse configuring or not fully optimized routing hard- and software. I'd only worry if it happens often.

PS: Yes, this question belongs, I think, on either [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) or [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com)